# 403 Forbidden on Rails app w/ Nginx, Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

First off, apologies: I know the 403 Forbidden question is a common one for Rails/Nginx installs, but none of the answers I've read so far have solved it for me.

Disclaimer: This is my first time deploying a Rails app somewhere that isn't Heroku. Please be gentle. ;)

Situation: I have a Rails app running on an Ubuntu 12.04 server, running Nginx (installed with Passenger).

I've deployed my app to my server correctly, but when I attempt to access the site, I receive a 403 Forbidden error.

Checking my error logs, I see:

```
2013/10/23 22:47:01 [error] 27954#0: *105 directory index of "/var/www/colepeters.com/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 50.3…server: colepeters.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "colepeters.com"
2013/10/23 22:47:10 [error] 27954#0: *106 directory index of "/var/www/colepeters.com/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 184…server: colepeters.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "colepeters.com"
2013/10/23 22:47:12 [error] 27954#0: *107 directory index of "/var/www/colepeters.com/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 151…server: colepeters.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "colepeters.com"
```

However, when checking permissions on this directory, I see that the user I have setup to use Nginx had both read and execute permissions on it.

Here's the relevant info from my nginx.conf:

```
user  XXXX;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/cole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.21;
    passenger_ruby /home/cole/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
       listen       80;
        server_name  colepeters.com www.colepeters.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /var/www/colepeters.com/current/public/;
        rails_env production;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
          root   /var/www/colepeters.com/current/public;
          index  index.html index.htm;
          # autoindex on;
        }
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on resolving this. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I have since corrected the erroneus passenger_ruby path, but the 403 Forbidden is persisting, even after restarting Nginx.

Comment: seems that the root path is not correct in nginx.conf.

Comment: Are you referring to the root path you've mentioned in your answer below, or the server/location root paths?

Comment: yes, the server location root paths.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can check the path of your passenger installation with

```
passenger-config --root
```

and the path of your ruby installation with

```
which ruby
```

then compare with the inserted in nginx.conf.

Comment: Thanks, having done this I noticed that my passenger_ruby directory was incorrect in nginx.conf; however, I'm still getting a 403 Forbidden, even after restarting Nginx.

Comment: 403 Forbidden (403 Forbidden) is an HTTP error code returned by the web server when the user or program attempts to gain access to a resource that the server does not allow

Comment: Thanks! For me i need to change this at /etc/nginx/passenger.conf

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error. In my case, I fixed it by removing the location / {} entry.
- or make sure that your user have permission to your rails project

```
...
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    root /www/kalender/public ;

    #charset koi8-r;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log;

    #location / {
       #root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
    #}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding `passenger_enabled on;` to the server directive worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was running a similar setup to yours and having the same problem with my nginx.conf file. Stumbling across the [Nginx pitfalls page](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) helped me solve it.

Your file looks similar to mine, so I'll share two things you may want to try that worked for me:

1. first, you have the `root` path in both the `server {}` block AND the `location {}` block. While not necessarily a problem, according to the docs linked above "If you add a root to every location block then a location block that isn't matched will have no root." I got rid of the roots in the location blocks but kept it in the server block.
2. move the 'index' directives (`index  index.html index.htm;`) out of the location block up to within the `http {}` block. The location blocks will inherit from this.

doing those two things and restarting the server worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the `location / {...}` section: the `passenger_enabled on` doesn't propagate from the `server {...}` into the `location / {...}`.

If you either remove `location / {...}`, or add `passenger_enabled on` to it, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

you also have config-file for passenger called `passenger.conf` by default in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/passenger.conf`
there you have to put correct roots.
you can check the roots with these two commands

```
passenger-config --root
```

and

which ruby

so when you get these roots you have to compare them with such in your `passenger.conf` file and it can be e.g. smth like this

```
#passenger-config --root
passenger_root /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
#which ruby
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby;
passenger_instance_registry_dir /var/run/passenger-instreg;
```

so if you use this way don't forget to make in http section of your `nginx.conf`

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/passenger.conf
```

as well as inserting in server section

```
passenger_enabled on;
```

Answer (score 1):

The key things are:
Remove the location block for the / section, assuming that the Rails application is accessible at /

Ensure the passenger_ruby is pointing to the rvm wrapper script for the selected ruby version

Add execute permissions to user, group and others to all the directories reaching to

```
/var/www/rails_app/public folder 
/var
/var/www
/var/www/rails_app
/var/www/rails_app/public_foler
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the root twice inside the server block and inside the /location block as well as directing nginx to use the index directive. Also remove the "/" after public folder

try doing this

```
user  XXXX;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/cole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.21;
    passenger_ruby /home/cole/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
       listen       80;
        server_name  colepeters.com www.colepeters.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /var/www/colepeters.com/current/public;
        rails_env production;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    }
}
```