# capistrano failed exit status 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, passenger

Running capistrano command to deploy `cap staging deploy`
fully runs through the entire process returning to the prompt.

However along the way, all files or directories listed under:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

are generating the following example errors

```
Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/dep/application/releases/20141009195446/bin ] on xx.xx.xx.xx
DEBUG[6d6a56cf] Command: [ -L /home/dep/application/releases/20141009195446/bin ]
DEBUG[6d6a56cf] Finished in 0.428 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[77ffc21a] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/dep/application/releases/20141009195446/bin ] on xx.xx.xx.xx
DEBUG[77ffc21a] Command: [ -d /home/dep/application/releases/20141009195446/bin ]
DEBUG[77ffc21a] Finished in 0.254 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

I have checked under ~/dep/application/shared/tmp/pids after launching `touch 'application/current/tmp/restart.txt'` command: the pid files are inexistent. So the failure above is material.  However I do not fathom the nature of it, I surmise it is attempting something with the aliases. But if I check the directory of the latest release, the aliases are all there and aliased files are properly returning the file content.

Don't know what to make of this type of error...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a failure per se.  Given that this is an aliased object, it does not exist and thus the action cannot occur.  It's just that the message is misleading...[as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553907/403-forbidden-on-rails-app-w-nginx-passenger)