# Nginx PageSpeed Module on Nginx from PhussionPassenger APT

Tags: nginx, passenger

I have installed nginx/1.12.1 and Phusion Passenger by APT from https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com repository. It's configured correctly within my Rails apps.

Thereafter, I want to improve nginx by adding **nginx pagespeed** module dynamically following this https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source to build **ngx_pagespeed** module and following this https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/ to compile dynamic module, by running :

`$ ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-${NPS_VERSION} ${PS_NGX_EXTRA_FLAGS}`

`$ make modules`

After that, I copied **ngx_pagespeed.so** from **objs/** folder into **/etc/nginx/modules** and of course loading the module into **nginx.conf** by adding `load_module modules/ngx_pagespeed.so;` on it. But when I reload nginx it's reproduced following error:

`nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5`

My question is:

1. **How do I add ngx_pagespeed module on nginx from PhusionPassenger APT?**
2. **What is the right `./configure` flags for compiling additional module without forgetting previous installed nginx (from PhusionPassenger APT) modules?**

Thank you

Comment: Please add which OS & passenger version # you are on.

Comment: I think you are using system nginx of different version and then compiling module using different version source code. You should check system version using `nginx -v` and use the same source code for module compiling? Also use `nginx -V` to get the compilation flags. Use the same flags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 Forbidden on Rails app w/ Nginx, Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553907/403-forbidden-on-rails-app-w-nginx-passenger)

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu xenial, you'll have an easier time adding your configure flags to the `passenger-install-nginx-module` script like so: `passenger-install-nginx-module --extra-configure-flags="--with-compat --add-dynamic-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-${NPS_VERSION} ${PS_NGX_EXTRA_FLAGS}"` instead of using the `nginx-extras` package, as matching the flags from the packaging process at phusion is a pain. You can read more about it here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/customizing_compilation_process.html

Comment: This hint was really useful to me, because it's the easier route then most tutorials on the web :)